# Salt enabling systemctl service using a custom service file

Tags: systemd, salt-stack

On salt modules how can I enable a custom service, provided a path to the service file.

```
custom_service:
 service.enable:
  - name: foo
  - path:
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it appears that you already have the systemd `foo.service` file on the miniom(s) at the appropriate location, and you would like to enable that service.

Not specific to Saltstack, but when service configuration files are updated, the daemon needs to be reloaded. That can be achieved as below in SLS:

```yaml
reload-systemd:
  module.run:
    - name: service.systemctl_reload

custom-service:
  service.enabled:
    - name: foo
```

*Note:*

If the service configuration file isn't on the minion at the required path, then you can use module such as `file.managed` to place it there.